Luke 23:42 How do Catholics explain it?

And he said, "Jesus, remember me when you come into your kingdom."

The more I study this verse, the more problems I find.
Context

This person (the criminal) can only know the public preaching of Jesus, who presents himself as a prophet announcing the coming Kingdom of God.

He cannot know his private conversations with the Apostles, where he reveals himself to be the Messiah, the Way, the Truth, and the Life.

Being a man of his time, for him the Messiah is a man who will occupy the throne of David, and the Kingdom of God will take place in the land of Israel.

There being no media, he only knows of Jesus by hearsay, unless he has encountered him in Jerusalem.

Being a criminal, the things of God are unlikely to occupy a place in his mind. Therefore, he is not well versed in the scriptures.


Difficulties

He is nailed to a cross and will die before the day is out. What happens next is irrelevant to him.

He speaks to Jesus, who will also die before the day is out. It is incongruous to ask for something from someone who will be no more.

No other book of the NT records this conversation and it's incongruent with Matthew 27:44.


Question
The most plausible explanation is that it is a dialogue created for theological reasons.
From the point of view of Catholicism, what could be the reason for creating this dialogue?

I feel like you are making quite a few assumptions: what the criminal knows, who he is etc

Consider that there was a written sign declaring him "King of the Jews" and that he would have overheard the various unrecorded conversations between Jesus and his followers during the several hours while they were crucified. He could easily have learned what they believed about his future and been influenced by their obvious faith and emotion. ¶But the fundamental question asked here is inappropriate; it assumes that the Catholic Church believes that this is a fictional dialogue. The question needs to prove that claim before it can reasonably be asked.

@RayButterworth. Learning theology while crucified? From the disciples that ran to hide? Be serious. Oh, I never said that the Church considered that fictional; I'm the one making that claim, based on Scriptures.

@CandidMoe says "I never said that the Church considered that fictional; I'm the one making that claim". Yet you are asking for Catholics to explain your claim even though they don't believe it.

"The most plausible explanation is that it is a dialogue created for theological reasons." reduces this question to a matter of one person's opinion in the face of a large body of evidence contained in 27 books written in the Greek language.

@RayButterworth. Matthew and Luke contradict each other. It's more probable that Luke added to Matthew than Matthew omitted from Luke. So, that passage has to be "created".

@NigelJ. Nobody seems to dispute the facts that I presented.

You are now launching into a new question - a supposed 'contradiction' which you need to fully document so that the (new) question can be considered and answered.

I don't see any 'facts' to dispute, myself.

@NigelJ Amuse your self disputing the "facts" presented by Ray: "Learning theology while crucified"

@NigelJ. Matthew and Luke contradict each other. That's a fact. Explain it

@CandidMoe asks: "From the point of view of Catholicism, what could be the reason for creating this dialogue?". That's like asking From the Southern Baptist point of view, what could be the reason that the Moon is made of green cheese?". The question is pointless.

The "contradiction" between Matthew and Luke is commonly taken to be the result of difference in timing. Matthew records what happened at the start of the thief's crucifixion. Luke records his change of mind while on the cross.  Seen in his conversion is awareness of his own evil "we are receiving what we deserve", awareness of Jesus's innocence, repentance, faith that Jesus is King of Heaven, prayer for forgiveness.. ie all the elements of true conversion.

Less commenting more answering!  But @candid - unfortunately you might get a generic answer from Catholicism that is less than entertaining to argue with a line from dei verbum

The more I see from this user, the less I am inclined to believe that he is participating here in good faith.

The way the dying thief was saved graphically and emphatically shows us the only way anyone can be saved.  He did no works of merit, he was a sinner through and through, but he repented and believed on Jesus and His mercy, he saw He was the King of Heaven, ie the Son of God.  He was saved purely by the grace of our Lord Jesus. Perhaps no conversion throughout Scripture is so useful as this one to understand the way to be saved.

This is very much a "when did you stop beating your wife" kind of question.

I’m voting to close this question because it is asking Catholics to defend something they do not teach.

The miracles performed by Jesus attracted people from all walks of life, thieves included. These thieves must have heard that a man named Jesus has raised the dead, walked on water among other miracles Jesus did.
The thieves must have been attracted to the sermons of Jesus because of the rumors that were spreading like wildfire about the wonders he was doing, so the two must have actually been in the crowd listening to his sermons, though one must have been listening actively and the other passively, that explains their division on the cross.
Jesus mentioned the kingdom of God in his sermons, so the thieves must have heard from their peers or families about a man named Jesus,so in their free time(a time when they were not busy looting) they must have said to each other, let us go and see for ourselves these miracles being performed so we may see if it is true or not.
Then they made inquiries on where Jesus was headed and they must have heard maybe he will be in the garden or the temple. That is how these thieves must have acquired the knowledge about the coming kingdom.
You are also wrong about this , the conversation is created for theological reasons
No one can make this stuff up, it needs to come from someone who was there on the cross or some other disciple inspired by the Holy Spirit to do it.
Even today, if someone started doing the miracles Jesus did, the rumors will spread so fast like wildfire, even thieves will break out of jail to witness it, and when they arrive at the location where the miracle man is, they will stop to hear his teachings.
There were other conversations on the cross that prove this conversation was not made up like:

Eli Eli Lamasabachthani(Jesus)
He is calling Elijah(The chief priests)
Truly, this man was the Son of God(Roman Centurion)


The Church proclaimed dogmatically in Vatican II that:

Holy Mother Church has firmly and with absolute constancy held, and continues to hold, that the four Gospels just named, whose historical character the Church unhesitatingly asserts, faithfully hand on what Jesus Christ, while living among men, really did and taught for their eternal salvation until the day He was taken up into heaven (see Acts 1:1). Indeed, after the Ascension of the Lord the Apostles handed on to their hearers what He had said and done. This they did with that clearer understanding which they enjoyed (3) after they had been instructed by the glorious events of Christ's life and taught by the light of the Spirit of truth. (2) The sacred authors wrote the four Gospels, selecting some things from the many which had been handed on by word of mouth or in writing, reducing some of them to a synthesis, explaining some things in view of the situation of their churches and preserving the form of proclamation but always in such fashion that they told us the honest truth about Jesus.(4) For their intention in writing was that either from their own memory and recollections, or from the witness of those who "themselves from the beginning were eyewitnesses and ministers of the Word" we might know "the truth" concerning those matters about which we have been instructed
Dei Verbum - chapter 5 - Paragraph 19

Three of the greatest saints in the history of the Church were witnesses to the crucifixion and, as the John says "his testimony is true".  If John, as an eye witness, had any desire to specifically contradict one of the other Gospels he certainly could have done it.  But he simply adds to the account and says, there's a lot more that could be said, but this is all I'm gonna say about that.
